# How to get libv8 gem installed on Windows with Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-2.0, therubyracer, libv8

I'm trying to get Devise to work, seems like it requires therubyracer gem. That requires the libv8 gem. I got an error it couldn't find python2, so I installed python 2.7 and copied python.exe to python2.exe... and added C:\Python27 to my path. Then it's complaining:

```
$ gem install therubyracer
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
  File "<string>", line 1
    'import
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
  File "<string>", line 1
    'import
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
/bin/sh: C:devbinmake.EXE: command not found
C:\dev\bin\make.EXE: *** [x64.release] Error 127
c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive 'c:/
Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNot
Found)
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
        from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python
Using compiler: C:\dev\mingw\bin\g++.EXE
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
        build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                      -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                      -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                      -S.x64  -Dv8_can_use_vfp_instructions=true


Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install an earlier version of libv8 on Windows, but apparenty rubyracer uses 3.11.8.5

```
gem install libv8 -v 3.11.8
```